# How to concisely bring a date to the desired form

Tags: javascript

I need to bring the date to the following form

```
2021-01-11 13:12:38
```

I wrote code like this, but can I do it more concisely?

```js
const date = new Date()
    const s = date.getSeconds()< 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds()
    const m = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()
    const h = date.getHours()< 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours()
    const d = date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate() : date.getDate()
    const mnth = date.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" + (date.getMonth()+1) : (date.getMonth()+1)
    const y = date.getFullYear()
    
    let newDate = `${y}-${mnth}-${d} ${h}:${m}:${s}`
    console.log(newDate)
```

Comment: My personal favorite for adding leading zeroes is `("0"+x).substr(-2)`

Comment: What about `x.padStart("0", 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].toString() + " " + new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0].toString()
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns) for concise and simple code.

```js
const formattedDate = dateFns.format(new Date(), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')

console.log(formattedDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')
```